# Postgres: "cumulative" view of table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, aggregate-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of changes like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS changes (
    entity_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    column_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    value JSONB NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

```
INSERT INTO changes VALUES ('1', 'height', to_jsonb(140), '01-01-2021 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO changes VALUES ('1', 'weight', to_jsonb(30), '01-01-2021 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO changes VALUES ('1', 'height', to_jsonb(145), '01-02-2021 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO changes VALUES ('1', 'weight', to_jsonb(34),'01-03-2021 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP);


 entity_id | column_id | value |     updated_at      
-----------+-----------+-------+---------------------
 1         | height    | 140   | 2021-01-01 00:00:00
 1         | weight    | 30    | 2021-01-01 00:00:00
 1         | height    | 145   | 2021-01-02 00:00:00
 1         | weight    | 34    | 2021-01-03 00:00:00
```

And I want to get kinda cumulative view of this table

```
entity_id  | height | weight |     updated_at      
-----------+--------+--------+---------------------
 1         | 140    | 30     | 2021-01-01 00:00:00
 1         | 145    | 30     | 2021-01-02 00:00:00
 1         | 145    | 34     | 2021-01-03 00:00:00
```

My current query looks working

```
SELECT
  entity_id,
  coalesce(change->'height', lag(change->'height', 1, null) over (partition by entity_id order by updated_at)) as height,
  coalesce(change->'weight', lag(change->'weight', 1, null) over (partition by entity_id order by updated_at)) as weight,
  updated_at
FROM (
    SELECT entity_id, json_object_agg(column_id, value) as change, updated_at FROM changes
    GROUP BY entity_id, updated_at
) as changes;
```

But I don't like `json_object_agg` here and I'm sure there is a way do it without redundant aggregations? some kind of using window aggregate function that I've missed.

UPD. [@SelVazi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4286884/selvazi) helped to make query better, but I feel it's not the final solution.

```
with cte as (
  SELECT
    entity_id,
    max(case when column_id = 'height' then value::int end) as height,
    max(case when column_id = 'weight' then value::int end) as weight,
    updated_at
  from changes
  GROUP by entity_id, updated_at
)
select
  entity_id,
  coalesce(height, lag(height) over (partition by entity_id order by updated_at)) as height,
  coalesce(weight, lag(weight) over (partition by entity_id order by updated_at)) as weight,
  updated_at
from cte;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more complicated that it may seem. Pivoting the height and weight to columns can be done with conditional aggregation, but then we have to fill the "missing" values.

I would assume that there could be gaps of more than one date for any of the two measures, which makes `lag()` the wrong fit in Postgres, since it can only look back over a predefined number of rows (and cannot ignore `null`  values).

We can demonstrate the problem with `lag()` by adding just one row at the end of your sample data:

| entity_id | column_id | value | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | height | 140 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | weight | 30 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | height | 145 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | weight | 34 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | weight | 140 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 |

One workaround uses a gaps-and-islands technique to put "missing" values in groups that start with a non-`null` value, which then becomes the new value.

```
select entity_id, updated_at,
    max(height) over(partition by entity_id, grp_height) height,
    max(weight) over(partition by entity_id, grp_weight) weight
from (
    select c.*,
        count(height) over (partition by entity_id order by updated_at) grp_height,
        count(weight) over (partition by entity_id order by updated_at) grp_weight
    from (
        select entity_id, updated_at,
            max(value::text) filter(where column_id = 'height') height,
            max(value::text) filter(where column_id = 'weight') weight
        from changes
        group by entity_id, updated_at
    ) c
) c
order by entity_id, updated_at
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ygipkvDi)

| entity_id | updated_at | height | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 140 | 30 |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 145 | 30 |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 145 | 34 |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 145 | 140 |

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `json_object_agg` you can use the conditional aggregation to get hight and width as columns :

```
SELECT entity_id, MAX(CASE WHEN column_id = 'height' THEN value::text END) AS height
                , MAX(CASE WHEN column_id = 'weight' THEN value::text END) AS weight
                , updated_at
FROM changes
GROUP BY entity_id, updated_at
```

The final query :

```
SELECT
  entity_id,
  coalesce(height, lag(height, 1, null) over (partition by entity_id order by updated_at)) as height,
  coalesce(weight, lag(weight, 1, null) over (partition by entity_id order by updated_at)) as weight,
  updated_at
FROM (
    SELECT entity_id, MAX(CASE WHEN column_id = 'height' THEN value::text END) AS height
                , MAX(CASE WHEN column_id = 'weight' THEN value::text END) AS weight
                , updated_at
    FROM changes
    GROUP BY entity_id, updated_at
) as changes;
```

Result :

```
entity_id   height  weight  updated_at
1           140     30      2021-01-01 00:00:00
1           145     30      2021-02-01 00:00:00
1           145     34      2021-03-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: The pivot is OK, but `lag(..., 1)` only covers for a single missing date. Although OP's sample data does not show that use case, one might expect other gaps in the data. In that case, your query gives a `null`  value for the concerned metric. Eg: https://dbfiddle.uk/_90KS9Ae

Comment: That's correct GMB, your solution do the job when more than one date is missing .. +1 deserved